# Unhandled Runtime Error. Error: (0 , swr__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_9__.default) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, next.js, mantine

So I am trying to fetch an API using NextJS and I am using SWR.

My code is as follows:

```
import useSWR from "swr";
const fetcher = (url: string) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());

export default function Home(){


  const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR(
    "https://api.github.com/repos/vercel/swr",
    fetcher
  );

return <></>
}
```

When saving the file I get the following message:

[image: error]

Answer (score 5):

The issue gets solved by adding `"use client";` at the top.

Refer to: https://swr.vercel.app/docs/with-nextjs

[image: using swr with next]

Answer (score 0):

you are using Next.js 13.4.9. However, the latest version of SWR is 1.2.3, which is compatible with Next.js 13.4.9. So, you can update SWR to the latest version without any problems.

```
npm install swr@1.2.3
```

Once you have updated SWR, you should no longer get the error.

Comment: I got error as "No matching version found for swr@1.2.3"

Comment: npm install swr@2.2.0.

 I assure you, your current version of SWR is not compatible with Next.js.

Comment: and Before installation clear the cache of the npm by useing this command npm cache clean --force

Comment: Thanks for the info. It showed the same error. I refer the documentation found that I have to use "use client"; at the top. https://swr.vercel.app/docs/with-nextjs